# summer bash 2015

Tags: feature-request, fun

just finished reading the [winter bash success story](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/?cb=1) and thought, hey that was fun and maybe it helped to improve the quality of stackexchange sites.

So my question is: Could we do a SUMMER BASH? during some days in summer ([June](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B96_Pepsi_SummerBash)), July or August.  You could earn your "beachwear", like board shorts, bikinis, surfboards, soft drinks, pina-coladas and caipirinhas ?

Comment: I'm totally imagining Summer Bash as that one episode of fanservice they stick into every single Anime series regardless of how serious it is.

Comment: mm... weird, I don't remember those @Mysticial (maybe I watch the non-serious ones?)

Comment: Already wearing sun glasses, so I'm prepared.

Comment: @Braiam You should watch more recent shows. :)

Comment: Move to Australia. It's summer during hat season.

Comment: so much about a FUN loving community :(

Answer (score 23):

Winter Bash is as much fun as it is, in small part, due to it taking place once a year. The Winter Bash adds some incentive to participate during the slower holiday season when visits, contributions, etc. tend to decline.

A 'Summer Bash', while probably a lot of fun, would potentially dilute the effectiveness (and fun) of Winter Bash.

And as @random said, join us here in the Southern Hemisphere for the Summer "Winter Bash".

Comment: "when visits, contributions, etc. tend to decline." me be like: On Jan 4, I got 53 reputation on SO and 59 reputation on Mathematics! Beat that!